# Why Is Data Programmed to Dream?

Tags: star-trek

I know Data is fully functional in every way, but he's still just an Android. Why is he programmed to dream when he doesn't even need sleep?

Comment: “Just” an android? Are you a *space racist?*

Comment: No lol! I love Data!! He's my favorite on TNG

Comment: Dr. Soong wanted to transfer a hidden message to Officer Spooner through Data's dreams... Oh sorry, wrong universe. :)

Comment: Sure, sure.  "I've got nothing against, androids, some of my best friends are androids!" :p

Comment: Why do you all keep talking about it like it's alive?  Sure, it's an extraordinary piece of engineering, but it is a machine!

Answer (score 9):

When he created Data, Dr Soong evidently believed that dreaming (and by extension, developing a subconscious) were an essential part of an android becoming more human.

Data's capacity to access his dream program has dramatically preceded his ability to *understand* what these dreams mean. He discovered the program by accident and is, essentially, playing with a tool that he doesn't fully comprehend. Presumably had his mental capabilities developed at a more organic pace, when he started dreaming it would have seemed less shocking.

> **DATA:** *An accident in Engineering shut down my cognitive functions for a short period of time, yet I seemed to remain conscious. I saw my
> father.*
>
> **WORF:** *You are very fortunate. That is a powerful vision.*
>
> **DATA:** *If it was a vision, I do not know how to proceed.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TNG: Birthright, Part I](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/242.htm)</sup></sub>

You might also want to note that Soong also created a system that allowed Data to feel emotions, again to allow him to act and be more human-like.

Comment: I'm trying desperately not to mention the parallels between this answer and the plot of HBO's Westworld (2016), and, obviously, failing. :)

Answer (score 1):

Data has a subconscious mind.  In addition to the dreams discussed in Valorum's answer from the episode Birthright, in Phantasms (Season 7, Episode 6) Data has subconscious knowledge of interphasic parasites feeding off crew members and disrupting ship operations, but this knowledge is expressed only in his (eventually, waking) dream state.  Ultimately, exploring Data's dream leads Data, Picard, and Geordi to a means of sterilizing the parasites.

So, it's not merely a further simulation/approximation of humanity, but an effective means of data processing (as it may be for us.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems '[dreaming](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/11893028_24)' is a function of even today's Artifical Neural Networks.

Look at this description of googles AI

> But they did more than that: they fed their neural networks with “white noise”, i.e. with “nothing”. And then a very interesting thing happened. The neural networks seemed to “imagine”, or “dream”. They set upon interpreting nothingness as an input. This is analogous to what happens in our brains during our sleep. With our senses turned off our brain has no external informational material to process. And yet our neurons do not cease to work. During so-called REM sleep, information about nothing is processed in our brain, and the output are dreams. Could Google’s neural networks be dreaming too?

- [source](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/george-zarkadakis/why-the-dreams-of-googles_b_7630292.html)
- [Googles original article](https://research.googleblog.com/2015/06/inceptionism-going-deeper-into-neural.html)

So if an early 21st century AI dreams, it seems logical that something (someone) as advanced as Data would too.

Comment: If they all start printing out electric sheep, we’re f—ed.

Answer (score 0):

From a programmer's point of view (since the Story aspects of StarTrek were already covered by others):

Dreaming is a kind of "background" and "cleaning up" process in the brain. Nearly every complex software uses this to free disk space, store and sort information for efficiency and other complicated or consuming tasks which shouldn't run during main process execution time because it takes away from processing power for "active" tasks.

For Data this could mean that he categorizes the information of the day, since he never forgets anything but he definitely should effectively store it.

I always thought of dreaming as the "garbage collection" of the brain.

Comment: Is there any indication that Data is defragging? If so, what was he doing before he started using this non-functioning program?

Comment: @Valorum: getting a dirty mind.

Comment: The fact that the program was waiting to be activated could be seen as Data not needing to defrag yet...?